# How to safely remove "Register..." phrases from login block in checkout page?

Tags: magento-1, onepage-checkout, login

How to remove the phrases like:

- Register and save time!
- Register with us for future convenience
- etc

from login block in one page checkout? They are located in the `login.phtml`. Can I just remove the corresponding lines in the `login.phtml`?

Comment: Which Magento version you are using?

Comment: These phrases only occur in Magento 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes you can remove that line but it will create issue while upgrading magento.

So you have to override this file or copy to the base theme of your store and then change all line you want.